# crawler taking url as 302 redirect, but actually there is no redirect why is this happening?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, web-crawler, magento-1.7

```
.htaccess
    ##### Add support for SVG Images and CSS3 Pie #####

    AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
    AddEncoding gzip svgz
    AddType text/x-component .htc
    DirectoryIndex index.php 

##### PHP Settings for your domain #####

<IfModule mod_php5.c> 
    php_value memory_limit 512M 
    php_value max_execution_time 18000 
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off 
    php_flag session.auto_start off 
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off 
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off 
</IfModule>

##### Search Engine redirects and rewrites for SEO purposes #####

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.alshop.com$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.alshop.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    ##### Redirect away from /index.php and /home   
    ##### Warning: This index.php rewrite will prevent Magento 
    ##### Connect from working. Simply comment out the  
    ##### following two lines of code when using Connect.
    ##### Please note - http://www. if not using www simply use http://

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.alshop.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    ##### Please note - http://www. if not using www simply use http://
    redirect 301 /home http://www.alshop.com

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]
</IfModule>


##### mod_deflate compresses your output to lower the file size being sent to the client #####

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    php_flag zlib.output_compression off
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars 
</IfModule>


##### Header Directives #####

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Last-Modified
</ifModule>



 ##### Disable ETags http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags #####

    FileETag None


##### Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides #####

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8


##### By default allow all access #####

    #Order allow,deny
    #Allow from all





## robots.txt

User-agent: *


## Crawl-delay parameter: number of seconds to wait between successive requests to the same server.
## Set a custom crawl rate if you're experiencing traffic problems with your server.
# Crawl-delay: 30

## DEVELOPMENT RELATED SETTINGS`

## Do not crawl development files and folders: CVS, svn directories and dump files
Disallow: /CVS
Disallow: /*.svn$
Disallow: /*.idea$
Disallow: /*.sql$
Disallow: /*.tgz$

## GENERAL MAGENTO SETTINGS

## Do not crawl Magento admin page
Disallow: /admin/

## Do not crawl common Magento technical folders
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /shell/
Disallow: /var/

## Do not crawl common Magento files
Disallow: /api.php
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /get.php
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /README.txt
Disallow: /RELEASE_NOTES.txt

## MAGENTO SEO IMPROVEMENTS

## Do not crawl sub category pages that are sorted or filtered.
Disallow: /*?dir*
Disallow: /*?dir=desc
Disallow: /*?dir=asc
Disallow: /*?limit=all
Disallow: /*?mode*
## Disallow: /*?*

## Do not crawl 2-nd home page copy (example.com/index.php/). Uncomment it only if you activated Magento SEO URLs.
Disallow: /index.php/

## Do not crawl links with session IDs
Disallow: /*?SID=

## Do not crawl checkout and user account pages
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /onestepcheckout/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customer/account/
Disallow: /customer/account/login/

## Do not crawl seach pages and not-SEO optimized catalog links
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/

## SERVER SETTINGS

## Do not crawl common server technical folders and files
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /cleanup.php
Disallow: /apc.php
Disallow: /memcache.php
Disallow: /phpinfo.php

## IMAGE CRAWLERS SETTINGS

## Extra: Uncomment if you do not wish Google and Bing to index your images
# User-agent: Googlebot-Image
# Disallow: /
# User-agent: msnbot-media
# Disallow: /

On Fri, May 29, 2015 at 9:51 AM, tech alshop <tech.alshop@gmail.com> wrote:
   .htaccess
    ##### Add support for SVG Images and CSS3 Pie #####

    AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
    AddEncoding gzip svgz
    AddType text/x-component .htc
    DirectoryIndex index.php 

##### PHP Settings for your domain #####

<IfModule mod_php5.c> 
    php_value memory_limit 512M 
    php_value max_execution_time 18000 
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off 
    php_flag session.auto_start off 
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off 
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off 
</IfModule>

##### Search Engine redirects and rewrites for SEO purposes #####

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.alshop.com$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.alshop.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    ##### Redirect away from /index.php and /home   
    ##### Warning: This index.php rewrite will prevent Magento 
    ##### Connect from working. Simply comment out the  
    ##### following two lines of code when using Connect.
    ##### Please note - http://www. if not using www simply use http://

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.alshop.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    ##### Please note - http://www. if not using www simply use http://
    redirect 301 /home http://www.alshop.com

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]
</IfModule>


##### mod_deflate compresses your output to lower the file size being sent to the client #####

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    php_flag zlib.output_compression off
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars 
</IfModule>


##### Header Directives #####

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Last-Modified
</ifModule>



 ##### Disable ETags http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags #####

    FileETag None


##### Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides #####

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8


##### By default allow all access #####

    #Order allow,deny
    #Allow from all
```

I am working in a eCommerce site with magento back-end. Everything was good in the past but suddenly dont know from where it started. some old urls and all the new urls that we are creating are not indexed because crawlers are considering the link as an 302 redirect, but actually in the browser if you see it is 200 ok . And these when we are using seo tools everything related to seo is also fine. When we examined little closer we found out some of these 302 status links are getting to 200 ok but after some times it goes back to 302 again. Can some one help me in solving this problem. Because of this none of our newly created pages are getting indexed.

Comment: Can you post your code so people can check over it?

Comment: Have you checked the server's logs to check that those pages are being served correctly to both users and bots? There's too many variables as to why your pages might be doing this, you'll just have to use good old-fashioned detective work to figure it out. It could be greedy regex in your htaccess, it could be the code in the pages returning the wrong HTTP response code. If it is just for bots then you should also check your robots.txt file.

Comment: hello i have edited the question with the .htaccess and tobots.txt file that we are running now. Can you please review the code. If you want anything more please let me know